# Search for files over local network servers directorys

Tags: vb.net, search, networking

Hi I want to build a search program that searches for a key word over any local networks the computer workstation has assess to like the search for files and folder function on any standard windows computer but with added feature it will also search across the networks servers its connected to?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1) Write code 2) run code 3) ??? 4) Profit

Comment: This question can't possibly be 'answered' - think of a starting point for your application:- a basic function that you need to get working before you can move to the next step, try and code that, if you get stuck on that part, then ask a question on that specific part.

Comment: When I see questions like this I can't help but wonder about the underlying problem you're trying to solve. But like said before this question is not easily answerable. Please refer to the faq for guidelines on asking questions in a way that will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) get local ip addresses
2) scan any local network you have access to
3) define the computer active on local network
4) looks for any shared folder on any active computer
5) looks for hidden share like C$, D$, E$, etc... on any active computer
6) retry point 4 and 5 using alternative credential (network admin login?)
7) now, simply search for file on remote computer, as you wolud do for a local file search (enumerate all folder in any share, enumerate any files in any folder, looks for subfolder... repeat until finished :-) )